# how to send a viber messages without users intercation (dynamically) in flutter app

Tags: flutter, viber

I am trying to build a flutter app that sends a a viber message to a viber chat group after some process is done. I already tried to launch the viber app using url_launcher but this solution doesn't suit my needs since i want my flutter app to use the viber account which is installed in the same device.

so what should i do to achieve this?

Comment: You should read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.